# Specify timezone and method name in pattern-formatter for logging in JBoss AS7

Tags: java, logging, jboss7.x, pattern-layout

How can I specify IST Timezone and the method name in the pattern-formatter of JBoss AS7 logging subsystem? I found that we can specify the UTC timezone as:

```
<pattern-formatter pattern="%z{utc}%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n"/>
```

But what about IST(Indian Standard Time, GMT+5.30) and the method name?

I have tried to use `{ist}` in place of `{utc}` for testing purpose, but that didn't work. When I have specified `{ist}` it is taking UTC time.

Comment: whats your system timezone?

Comment: @MukulGoel my system timezone is IST.